# Can I use Eclipse + ADT tutorials for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've started to get into Android Development and i downloaded the ADT bundle of the android developers page, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. So now I've decided to use Android Studio. Since its quite new there aren't many tutorials for it, whereas Eclipse + ADT has heaps of tutorials. I was wondering if I could use the thenewboston's tutorials (which were designed for eclipse) on Android Studio and still get the same results? Both the layouts look similar and they both use java so will there be any problems?

Comment: I tried so asked here most say that its the same only with the difference as told is ease of the setting of path. And when asked here some novice voted it down and some gave the same answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same code. For example how declare and use a textview in eclipse and androidstudio is the same, or how use button events is the same.

The difference is when you create a project, dependencies, libraries, and stuff configuration,  but the code instructions are the same because use java.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a tutorial which is IDE oriented, Eclipse tutorials won't help much with Android Studio.

Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA platform and IDEA tutorials may help you with configuring projects and other editor related configurations. And most importantly Android Studio won't provide support for the traditional Ant based projects since it uses Gradle build system. Of-course you can open and build Ant based projects which are created using IntelliJ IDEA but you cannot create new Ant projects in Android Studio.

If you are just looking for an alternative to Eclipse+ADT, my suggestion is to start with IntelliJ IDEA community edition first and then slowly migrate to Android Studio + Gradle. JetBrains website provides plenty of IDEA tutorials to start with.

hope this helps.

Comment: Could wou please tell the diff between the ADT(Intellij IDEA) and the Eclipse(Ant)

Comment: the main difference is Intellij use Gradle to biuld projects and Eclipse use ANT, another important characteristic is you can create differens apk in android studio at the same time, in eclipse you  can't. You only have Naviation editor in android studio, i think these difference are important but you have more.